# BackupServiceBinder restore only 1st saved version of a file

Tags: android, backup, cloud, restore

I got the sample for Restore/backup by android sdk samples, and its working fine, but updating only 1st version of data. So when i install to a device, modifying some data, after all the time when i uninstall/then re will be restored only that 1 version when i installed 1st the app whit that modification.

I think data after the 1st update to the cloud will never more change.
Here is my log for :
1- installing apk
2- changing the data state.
3- uninstalling the apk
4- reinstall
5- the 1st restored that will be restoring

> V/BackupManagerService(192): restoreAtInstall pkg=com.lynx.backup token=10

D/BackupManagerService(192): MSG_RUN_RESTORE observer=null

D/BackupManagerService(192): initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@

V/BackupServiceBinder(192): doRestore() invoked

V/BackupManagerService(192): Package com.lynx.backup restore version [1] is compatible with installed version [2]

D/BackupManagerService(192): awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{40f5f440 com.lynx.backup}

V/BackupServiceBinder(31754): doRestore() invoked

I/Backup time(31754): ..in loop..

D/BackupManagerService(192): agentConnected pkg=com.lynx.backup agent=android.os.BinderProxy@4136a118

D/BackupManagerService(192): initiateOneRestore packageName=com.lynx.backup

V/BackupManagerService(192): No next package, finishing restore

I/BackupManagerService(192): Restore complete.

D/BackupManagerService(192): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.lynx.backup flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }

V/BackupManagerService(192): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1

V/BRActivity(31754): datafile exists

V/BRActivity(31754):   mayo=true tomato=true filling=2130968577

V/PhoneStatusBar(259): setLightsOn(true)

V/BRActivity(31754): New radio item selected: 2130968579

V/BRActivity(31754): NEW STATE: mayo=true tomato=true filling=2130968579

V/BRActivity(31754): Checkbox toggled: android.widget.CheckBox@40eff6a8

V/BRActivity(31754): NEW STATE: mayo=false tomato=true filling=2130968579

D/LocalBluetoothProfileManager(32014): LocalBluetoothProfileManager construction complete

E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(352): Could not find a dictionary pack

D/BackupManagerService(192): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.lynx.backup flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }

V/BackupManagerService(192): removePackageParticipantsLocked: #1

D/LocalBluetoothProfileManager(32169): LocalBluetoothProfileManager construction complete

V/BackupManagerService(192): restoreAtInstall pkg=com.lynx.backup token=11

D/BackupManagerService(192): MSG_RUN_RESTORE observer=null

D/BackupManagerService(192): initiateOneRestore packageName=@pm@

V/BackupServiceBinder(192): doRestore() invoked

V/BackupManagerService(192): Package com.lynx.backup restore version [1] is compatible with installed version [2]

D/BackupManagerService(192): awaiting agent for ApplicationInfo{412aff08 com.lynx.backup}

D/BackupManagerService(192): agentConnected pkg=com.lynx.backup agent=android.os.BinderProxy@416c6f30

D/BackupManagerService(192): initiateOneRestore packageName=com.lynx.backup

V/BackupServiceBinder(32290): doRestore() invoked

I/Backup time(32290): ..in loop..

V/BackupManagerService(192): No next package, finishing restore

I/BackupManagerService(192): Restore complete.

D/BackupManagerService(192): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.lynx.backup flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }

V/BackupManagerService(192): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1

V/BRActivity(32407): datafile exists

V/BRActivity(32407):   mayo=true tomato=true filling=2130968577

V/PhoneStatusBar(259): setLightsOn(true)

D/BackupManagerService(192): couldn't find params for token 0

Comment: Need more info, how about some source.  Make sure to use bmgr to test your BackupAgent against the local transport. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/bmgr.html

Comment: Another thing to consider is that calling dataChanged() does not start a backup, it just marks you as ready for backup.  Google's backup service usually runs once per hour and that's when the data is backed up. As I said in previous comment it's best to test with bmgr and local transport to avoid that issue.